# How to start and stop execution of a JavaScript script with two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

I am animating an element in SVG so that it travels around a circular track. It runs around the track 3x and stops. I am using the [GSAP MotionPath plugin](https://greensock.com/motionpath/) to do the animation. I want to control the motion with start and stop buttons. The stop button can either pause the motion or stop it completely and have the element return to its place - whichever involves the simpler method.

I managed to get the animation to start by clicking the "START" button.  But I can't get it to stop by clicking the "STOP" button.

I show below the animation with the start button.

```js
function myFunction(){
     gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);
     gsap.to("#comet-horizontal", {
        duration: 5, 
        repeat: 2,
        repeatDelay: 0,
        yoyo: false,
        ease: "none",
        motionPath:{
             path: "#racetrack",
             align: "#racetrack",
             autoRotate: true,
             alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
        }
     });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  /*background-color: black;*/
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  /* Fix Safari rendering bug */
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
circle {
  fill: pink;
}
#button{
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px; 
 background-color: orange;
 position: relative;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom:  5px;
}
#button2{
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px; 
 background-color: yellow; 
 position: relative;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom:  5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.3/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">START</button>
<button id="button2">STOP</button>
<svg
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 338.66667 190.5">
    <path
       id="racetrack"
style="font-variation-settings:normal;opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffaaaa;stroke-width:2.32673;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers fill stroke;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1"
       d="M 184.04496,79.375006 A 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 132.29166,131.1283 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 80.538365,79.375006 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 132.29166,27.621698 a 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 51.7533,51.753308 z" />   
    <path
       id="comet-horizontal"
style="font-variation-settings:normal;opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#00d3ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:2.82278;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1"
       d="m 241.75652,61.794127 v 2.645839 l -13.22916,-0.661459 v -0.66146 -0.66146 z"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccc" />
</svg>
</body>
```

I browsed StackOverflow but could not find the answer. For example, [How to control the execution of javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253443/how-to-control-the-execution-of-javascript-functions) is a similar question to mine but the asker wants a new function to start after the first one is stopped.

I cannot use typical animation functions such as `animation-play-state` since the animation is using a GreenSock script.

I also tried out the top solution from [How to stop a function during its execution - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793294/how-to-stop-a-function-during-its-execution-javascript) but it didn't work for me (maybe because I implemented it wrongly). I am having trouble writing the "if" condition for when the Stop button is clicked. I tried `if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)` but it didn't work.

Below is the solution mentioned above in the last link.

```
function foo1(){
  console.log("Foo started...");
  if(prompt("Type 1 to terminate right now or anything else to continue...") == "1"){
    return;  // Function will terminate here if this is encountered
  }
  console.log("Foo ending...");  // This will only be run if something other than 1 was entered
}

foo1();
```

I would prefer to stick with vanilla JS solutions if possible rather than JQuery because I am not familiar with JQuery, but if a JQuery solution is the easiest way of doing it, I am open to it.

This is the attempt to implement the "foo1" solution that failed:

```
     function myFunction(){
     gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);
     gsap.to("#comet-horizontal", {
        duration: 5, 
        repeat: 2,
        repeatDelay: 0,
        yoyo: false,
        ease: "none",
        motionPath:{
             path: "#racetrack",
             align: "#racetrack",
             autoRotate: true,
             alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
        }
     });
    if (document.getElementById("button2").clicked == true)
            return;
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: How about changing the name of `myFunction` to `start` and then adding a `stop` function also: `<button id="button2" onclick="stop()">STOP</button>`?

Comment: @MikeM I tried something like that but it didn't work. Stopping a running function has to be done in the same function apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`gsap.to` method](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.to()) returns a [Tween object](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween) with which you can control the animation. It has `pause`, `resume`, `restart` and several other useful methods.

Here I adapted your script:

- Renamed the HTML buttons with more telling names.
- Attached the click handlers in code, not via HTML attribute
- Added a global variable to allow each event handler to access the above mentioned object
- Added the logic to pause and resume the animation
- Change the `repeat: 2` parameter to `repeat: -1`, so the animation has no end.

```js
let tween; // global so both handlers can access it

document.getElementById("buttonStart").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (tween) { // Not first time:
        tween.resume(); // Continue from where it was paused
        return;
    }
    gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);
    tween = gsap.to("#comet-horizontal", {
        duration: 5, 
        repeat: -1,
        repeatDelay: 0,
        yoyo: false,
        ease: "none",
        motionPath:{
             path: "#racetrack",
             align: "#racetrack",
             autoRotate: true,
             alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
        }
    });
});

document.getElementById("buttonStop").addEventListener("click", function () {
    tween?.pause();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  /*background-color: black;*/
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  /* Fix Safari rendering bug */
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
circle {
  fill: pink;
}
#button{
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px; 
 background-color: orange;
 position: relative;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom:  5px;
}
#button2{
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px; 
 background-color: yellow; 
 position: relative;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom:  5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.3/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="buttonStart">START</button>
<button id="buttonStop">STOP</button>
<svg
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 338.66667 190.5">
    <path
       id="racetrack"
style="font-variation-settings:normal;opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffaaaa;stroke-width:2.32673;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers fill stroke;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1"
       d="M 184.04496,79.375006 A 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 132.29166,131.1283 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 80.538365,79.375006 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 132.29166,27.621698 a 51.753304,51.753307 0 0 1 51.7533,51.753308 z" />   
    <path
       id="comet-horizontal"
style="font-variation-settings:normal;opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#00d3ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:2.82278;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1"
       d="m 241.75652,61.794127 v 2.645839 l -13.22916,-0.661459 v -0.66146 -0.66146 z"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccc" />
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: It works to a certain extent. The start button will start the motion before 3 cycles have been completed but won't after the 3 cycles have been done. @trincot

Comment: That is because you have mentioned a `repeat` parameter with value 2? Wasn't that the purpose? If you don't want that, then just set the `repeat` parameter to -1, and it will go on indefinitely. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I got confused and didn't frame the question properly, and left it open for "pause" and "stopping". The solution works for start and pause. To get the start button to restart the animation, the page has to be refreshed I guess.

Comment: There is also a `restart` method on the Tween object. If you want that, just replace `resume` with `restart` or create a third button that does that.

Comment: I could try ```endElement()``` with an ```onclick``` function involving the stop button in a new script to stop the execution completely though the comet might disappear from the page. Restarting might involve using ```beginElement()```. I will test it out. I don't know if it's possible to end completely the running of a JS function from outside this function. But I am happy with the solution because I need a pause function.